# How to return all strings

Tags: python, list, return

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import fbconsole
here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


def fbfeed():
    fbconsole.APP_ID = '588914247790498'
    fbconsole.AUTH_SCOPE = ['publish_stream', 'publish_checkins', 'read_stream', 'offline_access']
    fbconsole.authenticate()
    newsfeed = fbconsole.get('/me/home')
    newsfeedData = newsfeed["data"]
    for status in newsfeedData:
        fromn = [status['from']['name']]
        name = [status.get('name', None)]
        description = [status.get('description', None)]
        if description == name is None:
            return fromn
        elif description is None:
            return fromn.extend(name)
        elif name is None:
            return fromn.extend(description)
        else:
            return fromn + name + description
```

My code returns only one string, but when I use **print** instead of **return** - it prints ALL of results. How can I return the same results, as in case of **print**??

Comment: change you returns for yield then you can ``for f in feeds():``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use return it exits the function and doesn't keep iterating through the loop like it does with print. Try yield.

Comment: ok, it works, and how can I define this result to a variable? I want to send it to a mako template.

Comment: When you use the yield statement it turn the function into a generator, which can be used a lot like a list. The easiest way to convert this to a list is just to say x = list(fbfeed())

Comment: it shows me output like a `[u'\u0406\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0430 \u0421\u0435\u0445', None, u'Change Ur Template to R3D Here--> http://bit.ly/14NYfaJ?477259&cid=theme']` how to fix it???

Comment: That's probably worthy of starting another question. I believe those are unicode characters. Python has a str.decode('utf-8') or something like that, but I'm not too familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when your loop hits the first `return` statement the function will exit and the loop will not continue. Using `print` will allow the loop to continue.

Two options are to create a list before you start looping, add the statuses to the list in the loop, and then return the list after the loop.

Using the `yield` keyword instead of `return` will allow *other* functions to loop over the result. More details on the `yield` keyword can be found here: [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) (plus in the actual docs: http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html?highlight=yield#yield-expressions).